# one-sided saturation with op-amp and RC high pass filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, discharge, saturation

I am working with a photodetecting circuit built as follow:

[image]

When I drive an LED ON and OFF, I get the following waveforms:

[image]

Blue indicates that the LED is turned on when a voltage is high and turned off when low.

Yellow shows brightness reading after RC high pass filter.

The lower envelope of the yellow line looks like a voltage discharging pattern of an RC circuit.

The problem is, however, the upper envelope seems like a saturated signal.

I can it more clearly by reducing the capacitance to 10 uF:

[image]

By reducing capacitance from 47 uF to 10 uF, a discharging pattern in the upper envelope after a short saturated duration can be seen.

But I am curious that

1. Why only the upper envelope is saturated? Why not for the lower envelope?
2. Why the upper envelope is saturated at nearly 200-300 mV, not around `VCC+`, 5 V?

*For your information*, both the upper and the lower envelopes are not saturated if I remove the RC HPF and see voltage readings:

[image]

Comment: Don't expect an op-amp to arbitrarily be able to drive a 50 ohms load without giving some problems and messing up the signal. If you read the data sheet of the TL972 you'd see that the device is able to source maybe a mA or so but the good side is that it can sink up to 80 mA but that won't help fix the waveform.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the op-amp output when it's doing this.

Comment: And please provide a picture of your actual circuit. I suspect grounding/decoupling issues.

Comment: Looking at the data sheet, I'm almost certain you have decoupling problems. You're apparently using 10 uF electrolytics for decoupling, and you must use good low-ESR ceramics. This also suggests a cavalier approach to grounding, and this op amp has gain to 10 MHz. Please post a picture of your circuit.

Comment: Well I got it. But it is quite a mess... I will post my actual circuit with some labels and tags as soon as possible.

Comment: And yes. I am using electrolytic for those 10 uF.

Comment: Here's the actual circuit.  
From the top: http://i.imgur.com/9wQ1JjH.jpg  
From the right: http://i.imgur.com/B4pOjsA.jpg  
Sorry for it's quite a mess...